# How to show protocols and cipher suites available to Jetty HTTPS clients?

Tags: java, ssl, https, cryptography, jetty

I have configured Jetty embedded server to include/exclude some protocols and cipher suites. Is there way to report those on working service? I think about something like `getSupportedCipherSuites()` and `getSupportedProtocols()` of `javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocket` but for Jetty server objects. My code already shows things from configration:

```
HTTPSPDYServerConnector SSLconnector = new HTTPSPDYServerConnector(server, sslContextFactory);
SSLconnector.setPort(PortHTTPS);
...
server.setConnectors(new Connector[] { SSLconnector });
...
showInfo(sslContextFactory.getIncludeCipherSuites());
showInfo(sslContextFactory.getExcludeCipherSuites());
showInfo(sslContextFactory.getIncludeProtocols());
showInfo(sslContextFactory.getExcludeProtocols());
...
server.start();
```

Now I want to see what protocols and cipher suites are available for clients.

**EDIT (more info):**

My environment can work with those protocols:

```
SSLv2Hello
SSLv3
TLSv1
TLSv1.1
TLSv1.2
```

This is result of `SSLServerSocket.getSupportedProtocols()` that is reported by http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/javax.net.ssl/SSLServerSocketgetSupportedProtocols.htm

But with Jetty environment I do not know how to get such list. I excluded some protocols by calling
    `sslContextFactory.addExcludeProtocols()` (I disabled `TLSv1.2` because of Chrome bug [ERR_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_SIGNATURE_FAILED in Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18373699/err-ssl-client-auth-signature-failed-in-google-chrome))

How can I get list of protocols available (not excluded) for Jetty server?

I suppose that for my environment such result will be:

```
SSLv2Hello
SSLv3
TLSv1
TLSv1.1
```

(TLSv1.2 was disabled)

Comment: What do you need to know that this doesn't already show?

Comment: It do not show me available protocols like `TLSv1.2` if I do not use it in included/excluded protocols.

Comment: I don't understand the part starting 'if I do not use it ...'.

Comment: I can use: `sslContextFactory.setExcludeCipherSuites(new String[]{"TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA",...)` and then I see `TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA` in logs. But I will not see it in logs if I do not exclude it even if it is available and can be used by clients.

Comment: Try selectCipherSuites().

Comment: Both `selectProtocols()` and `selectCipherSuites()` needs arrays of supported protocols/ciphers. My question is: how to get them from  Jetty server? I can get them using `javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocket` but it needs created server socket. More information on my edited question.

Answer (score 2):

I've just gone through a similar problem.

The way Jetty works, it instantiates a default `SSLEngine` and then it applies exclusions and other preferences. By default, Jetty 9.4 excludes the following protocols:

```java
this.addExcludeProtocols("SSL", "SSLv2", "SSLv2Hello", "SSLv3");
```

Ciphers are managed in a similar way, but you can uge regexes. By default, Jetty 9.4 excludes the following:

```java
this.setExcludeCipherSuites("^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$");
        this.addExcludeCipherSuites("^TLS_RSA_.*$");
        this.addExcludeCipherSuites("^SSL_.*$");
        this.addExcludeCipherSuites("^.*_NULL_.*$");
        this.addExcludeCipherSuites("^.*_anon_.*$");
```

If you call the include/exclude methods yourselp, you will have to deal with the particular sequence of processing that Jetty performs, which is potentially confusing. So I recommend you use the setter methods first with empty arrays, in order to clear anything Jetty put in place by default, and *then* add your preferred items. Example:

```java
// empty the collections, we don't need no education
sslContextFactory.setExcludeProtocols(new String[]{});
sslContextFactory.setExcludeCipherSuites(new String[]{});

// tell me what you want, what you really really want
sslContextFactory.setIncludeProtocols("TLSv1","TLSv1.1","TLSv1.2");
sslContextFactory.setIncludeCipherSuites(omgIveNeverSeenSuchABigArrayOfCiphers);
```

If you need a list of ciphers that a specific Java client supports, run that client with `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake:verbose` and look for ClientHello messages.